# SQL string (help converting date number to year)

Tags: sql, syntax

I have a date field then a number field ( # of Years) I want to add then covert back to a date.

```
partlot.MfgDt + Part.number01
```

What would be the simplest way?

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time and string handling, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer here.

Comment: ANSI SQL way: `datecolumn + cast(integercolumn as interval year)`

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this is the query in **SQL Server**

`SELECT cast(DATEADD(year, YearsCol, DateCol) as datetime) as newDate FROM TableName`

`YearsCol` is your number field and `DateCol` is your date field

If the fields are from two different **tables** you need to `join` the tables based on their relation, but in this case, it is not clear what is the relation between tables?

Comment: So i did something like is and got an error  Possiable SQL injection  

SELECT cast(DATEADD(year, part.number01, PartLot.MfgDt) as datetime) as newDate Part

Comment: From what table? seems you've forgotten table name.

Comment: And if these two columns are from two different tables, you should use join clause to combine two tables data

Comment: yes part table  number02 field (part.naumber01)     PartLot table mfgDt field     (partlot.MfgDt)

Comment: what is their relation? Show me both tables columns and PKs and FKs in your question section (image or text).

Comment: I posted in question sections,  is this what your looking for?

Comment: not exactly, what I said was the relation between two tables. What you've posted is just a long query...

Comment: I guess I am confussed on what you need, wont the query show the current relations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242245/discussion-between-mahooresorkh-and-marquee-phillip).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to add year in Date column.

In **SQL Server** you can use this:-

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, IntervalYear, DateColumn) FROM TableName
```

Comment: I added a pic o the post

Comment: I am trying to create a caluated field,   take a date field add a number field and cover it back to a date.

Comment: @MarqueePhillip SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, '2022-02-22 01:11:12.540')  is adding  1 year with 2022-02-22 01:11:12.540. So the result is 2023-02-22 01:11:12.540. is it your expected result?

Comment: Yes,  PartLot.mfgdt (datefield)  then + Part.number01    ex..  1/1/2020   + 2.0 in number field then result 1\1\2022

Comment: SELECT DATEDD(year, Part.Number01, PartLot.MfgDt)

I tried this with now avil